# What is grammatically wrong with ''unless if''?

Tags: conjunctions, negation, redundancy

> [[Source:]](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/unless) `!!` Do not say 'unless if'.
>   [✓] Don't call him **unless**   it's urgent [✓]
>   [✘] [Don't call him] **unless if** it's urgent. [✘]

Please beware of my [tribulation with **unless**](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/12238/5306).

Footnote: [This Wordreference.com question](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2521035&p=12698417#post12698417) motivated this.

Comment: What do you think of the sentence "Call him if if it's urgent"?

Comment: In your earlier question, the source you quoted said you could replace **unless** with **if not**.  try that with your example in this question:  Don't call him unless if it's urgent >>> Don't call him **if not if** it's urgent.  Is it clear to you why that would be incorrect? Yes no yes?

Comment: what is wrong with _beyond from_, or _behind before_, or _whenever because_, or _always once_, or _besides except_?

Comment: @snailboat I agree: that sentence is wrong. But **unless* means more than just 'if'.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Thanks. I agree that 'if if not' is wrong. But what did you mean in your 2nd comment? `behind before` and `besides except` sound wrong, but the other 3 prepositional phrases sound right?

Comment: Not to me they don't. I meant them all as bad examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepositional phrase (late Middle English) *on lesse (than)* which became modern *unless* originally meant "in circumstances that fall short of {X}".  The modern word still has that meaning and  that "syntactic shape".

{X} can't be a conditional statement; {X} must be a declaration:

**Don't come to me unless *you have no other recourse*.**

**Don't cross the street unless *the light is green*.**

P.S. The "un" of "unless" does not mean "not" as it does in the word "untidy", for example.

Answer (score 3):

> Don't call him **unless** it's urgent.

According to [American Heritage of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unless), **unless**, used as a conjunction means:

> Except on the condition that; except under the circumstances that.

Or simpler we can say **except if**.

For this reason you can't make a construct like this:

> Don't call him **except if if** it's urgent.